# DB2 SQL Triggers

Tags: sql, triggers, db2

I'm pretty new (like read-about-it-5-hours-ago-new) into Triggers, so I need some help on this:

Create the table `TelefonnummerAenderung` and delete all data in it if it already exists.
Create a Trigger meeting the following conditions: (I hope it's ok for you guys if I don't translate all the table names and attributes into English.)

-a change of the attribute `Telefonnummer` in `KundenKontaktDaten` is only allowed 15 secs after the last change
-otherwise a `SIGNAL SQLSTATE '70001'` is thrown

-while changing the `Telefonnummer` in `KundenKontaktDaten` a new entry in `TelefonnummerAenderungen` is created containing the old `Telefonnummer` and the time it was changed

-if the new and the old `Telefonnummer` are the same, no trigger action takes place

The two tables are the following:

`KundenKontaktDaten`: (edit: I forgot, `Kunden_Nr` is also referencing `Kunde(Kunden_Nr)`.  It should not matter for the task, just saying)

```
 create table KundenKontaktDaten
 ( Kunden_Nr int not null primary key,
   Twitter_Id  Varchar(40), 
   Google_Id bigint,
   Facebook_Id bigint,
   Skype_Id Varchar(64),
   Telefonnummer Varchar(50)
 );
```

`TelefonnummerAenderungen`:

```
create table TelefonnummerAenderungen 
( GEAENDERT_AM TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, 
  KUNDEN_NR INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  ALTE_NUMMER VARCHAR(50), 
  FOREIGN KEY(KUNDEN_NR) 
    REFERENCES KUNDE(KUNDEN_NR)
    ON DELETE CASCADE 
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT, 
  PRIMARY KEY(GEAENDERT_AM, KUNDEN_NR)
);
```

My solution(java code; should not matter concerning the question):

```
static public void triggerAnlegen(Connection con) throws SQLException {
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    try {
        stmt.execute("create table TelefonnummerAenderungen ( GEAENDERT_AM TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, KUNDEN_NR INTEGER NOT NULL, ALTE_NUMMER VARCHAR(50), FOREIGN KEY(KUNDEN_NR) REFERENCES KUNDE(KUNDEN_NR) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT, PRIMARY KEY(GEAENDERT_AM, KUNDEN_NR))");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        if(e.getErrorCode()==-601){
            stmt.execute("DELETE FROM TelefonnummerAenderungen");
        }
    }
    try{
        stmt.execute("CREATE TRIGGER haTrigger AFTER UPDATE OF Telefonnummer ON KundenKontaktDaten REFERENCING NEW as n_row OLD as o_row FOR EACH ROW WHEN (o_row.Telefonnummer<>n_row.Telefonnummer) "+
                        "BEGIN " +
                            "IF(NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TelefonnummerAenderungen WHERE Kunden_Nr=n_row.Kunden_Nr)) " +
                            "THEN " +
                                "INSERT INTO TelefonnummerAenderungen VALUES (CURRENT TIMESTAMP,n_row.Kunden_Nr,o_row.Telefonnummer); " +
                            "ELSEIF(CURRENT TIMESTAMP<((SELECT GEAENDERT_AM FROM TelefonnummerAenderungen WHERE Kunden_Nr=n_row.Kunden_Nr) + 15 seconds)) " +
                            "THEN " +
                                "UPDATE KundenKontaktDaten SET Kunden_Nr=o_row.Kunden_Nr,Twitter_Id=o_row.Twitter_Id,Google_Id=o_row.Google_Id,Facebook_Id=o_row.Facebook_Id,Skype_Id=o_row.Skype_Id,Telefonnummer=o_row.Telefonnummer;" +
                                "SIGNAL SQLSTATE '70001'; " +
                            "ELSE " +
                                "UPDATE TelefonnummerAenderungen SET GEAENDERT_AM=CURRENT TIMESTAMP,ALTE_NUMMER=o_row.Telefonnummer WHERE Kunden_Nr=n_row.Kunden_Nr; " +
                            "END IF;" +
                        "END");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

SQL-only:

```
CREATE TRIGGER haTrigger 
  AFTER UPDATE OF Telefonnummer ON KundenKontaktDaten 
  REFERENCING 
    NEW as n_row 
    OLD as o_row 
  FOR EACH ROW WHEN (o_row.Telefonnummer <> n_row.Telefonnummer)
  BEGIN
    IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                    FROM TelefonnummerAenderungen 
                    WHERE Kunden_Nr=n_row.Kunden_Nr)
       )
    THEN
      INSERT INTO TelefonnummerAenderungen 
      VALUES 
        (CURRENT TIMESTAMP, n_row.Kunden_Nr, o_row.Telefonnummer);
    ELSEIF (CURRENT TIMESTAMP < ((SELECT GEAENDERT_AM 
                                  FROM TelefonnummerAenderungen 
                                  WHERE Kunden_Nr=n_row.Kunden_Nr) + 15 seconds)
           )
    THEN
      UPDATE KundenKontaktDaten
      SET Kunden_Nr = o_row.Kunden_Nr, 
          Twitter_Id = o_row.Twitter_Id, 
          Google_Id = o_row.Google_Id, 
          Facebook_Id = o_row.Facebook_Id, 
          Skype_Id = o_row.Skype_Id,
          Telefonnummer = o_row.Telefonnummer;
      SIGNAL SQLSTATE '70001';
    ELSE 
      UPDATE TelefonnummerAenderungen
      SET GEAENDERT_AM = CURRENT TIMESTAMP, 
          ALTE_NUMMER = o_row.Telefonnummer 
      WHERE Kunden_Nr = n_row.Kunden_Nr; 
    END IF;
  END
```

I used the `AFTER UPDATE OF [...]` because I was not sure, whether (when using `BEFORE UPDATE OF [...]`) the query, which caused the trigger to trigger, is still being executed after the trigger handling .

[**edit**: changed it to `BEFORE` and dropped the

```
UPDATE KundenKontaktDaten 
SET Kunden_Nr = o_row.Kunden_Nr,
    Twitter_Id = o_row.Twitter_Id,
    Google_Id = o_row.Google_Id,
    Facebook_Id = o_row.Facebook_Id,
    Skype_Id = o_row.Skype_Id,
    Telefonnummer = o_row.Telefonnummer;
```

because I was getting cascading trigger errors otherwise ; won't change the code here though for matter of transparency]

This is (obviously) my homework (no real-world-problem, hope that's ok, and we get graded automatically by some test function we don't know - that way I know my results are wrong.
But I don't know which part of it is wrong, so I need some help on this.

---

**Edit 2:**
My post is getting kind of confusing, sorry. I thought creating an answer would be more clear than further editing of my post:

After further testing I figured out the problem with the first attempt:

When using 'AFTER UPDATE...' in my trigger, it's too late and I can't undo the changes made to 'KundenKontaktDaten' although the 15 seconds didn't pass, since it would result in cascading trigger calls.

When using 'BEFORE UPDATE...' DB2 restricts me of using any kind of INSERT or UPDATE.

So I figured out I have to use `INSTEAD OF`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER haTrigger INSTEAD OF UPDATE ON KundenKontaktDaten REFERENCING NEW as n_row OLD as o_row FOR EACH ROW 
         BEGIN 
    IF(o_row.Telefonnummer<>n_row.Telefonnummer) THEN 
                    IF(NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TelefonnummerAenderungen WHERE Kunden_Nr=n_row.Kunden_Nr)) THEN 
            UPDATE KundenKontaktDaten SET Kunden_Nr=n_row.Kunden_Nr,Twitter_Id=n_row.Twitter_Id,Google_Id=n_row.Google_Id,Facebook_Id=n_row.Facebook_Id,
            Skype_Id=n_row.Skype_Id,Telefonnummer=n_row.Telefonnummer WHERE Kunden_Nr=o_row.Kunden_Nr;
                        INSERT INTO TelefonnummerAenderungen VALUES (CURRENT TIMESTAMP,n_row.Kunden_Nr,o_row.Telefonnummer);
                    ELSEIF(CURRENT TIMESTAMP<((SELECT GEAENDERT_AM FROM TelefonnummerAenderungen WHERE Kunden_Nr=n_row.Kunden_Nr) + 15 seconds)) THEN
                        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '70001';
                    ELSE
            UPDATE KundenKontaktDaten SET Kunden_Nr=n_row.Kunden_Nr,Twitter_Id=n_row.Twitter_Id,Google_Id=n_row.Google_Id,Facebook_Id=n_row.Facebook_Id,
            Skype_Id=n_row.Skype_Id,Telefonnummer=n_row.Telefonnummer WHERE Kunden_Nr=o_row.Kunden_Nr;
                        UPDATE TelefonnummerAenderungen SET GEAENDERT_AM=CURRENT TIMESTAMP,ALTE_NUMMER=o_row.Telefonnummer WHERE Kunden_Nr=n_row.Kunden_Nr;
                    END IF;
             END IF;
         END
```

resulting in yet another error:

> DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-159, SQLSTATE=42809,
>   SQLERRMC=GRP13.KUNDENKONTAKTDATEN;TABLE;UNTYPED VIEW

Since I have no idea, does anyone know what's the problem with that one? If neither `Before` nor `After` nor `Instead of` works, then I'm kind of running out of options.

Comment: I suggest you take Java out of the picture until you figure out the trigger. Show only the SQL code and explain how the trigger execution results differ from what you expect.

Comment: I just edit my post and added only the sql query. Also, i did some further testing and if i change the attribute 'Telefonnummer' too fast (<15 seconds apart), now I'm getting:  An error occurred in a triggered SQL statement in trigger "GRP13.HATRIGGER".  Information returned for the error includes SQLCODE "-724",SQLSTATE "54038" <- shouldn't i get sqlstate=70001 since that's what im throwing?

Comment: nvm, changed the part with 'AFTER UPDATE OF...` to 'BEFORE UPDATE OF' -> i'm getting the correct SQLSTATE now; still not working though, and i dont have an idea why(like i said, its automatically testing this, and i dont have source code for the test). It works while manually testing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to include the `UPDATE` of `KundenKontaktDaten` in the trigger, because the table is already modified by the statement that invokes the trigger. It probably should look somewhat like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER haTrigger 
AFTER UPDATE OF Telefonnummer ON KundenKontaktDaten 
REFERENCING NEW as n_row OLD as o_row 
FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN (o_row.Telefonnummer<>n_row.Telefonnummer)
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS ( 
    SELECT 1 FROM TelefonnummerAenderungen a
    WHERE a.Kunden_Nr = o_row.Kunden_Nr 
    AND a.GEAENDERT_AM > CURRENT TIMESTAMP - 15 seconds
  )
  THEN -- within the 15 sec. window, record old telephone number
    INSERT INTO TelefonnummerAenderungen 
    VALUES (CURRENT TIMESTAMP, o_row.Kunden_Nr,o_row.Telefonnummer);
  ELSE -- too late
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '70001';
  END IF;
END
```

PS. Not tested.

PPS. You probably should store `GEAENDERT_AM` also in `KundenKontaktDaten` to avoid the extra query.

Comment: It's working, I had clearly a wrong idea of triggers: I thought this will still change the entry in KundenKontaktDaten, because it triggers after that was done(well, but it doesn't). Thank You!